# Cart quantity of iPhoneX has been reduced to 9 from 10 due to insufficient stock

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

Hybris stock level falling back to 9. I have an iPhone X in stock for 10 quantities, Anytime user places an order it return a low stock message then quantity falls back to 9.

Any help would be appreciated. I know there isn't any code to show on here but trying to get an input from All. Just want to know how to go about writing the logic to solving the low stock quantity issue.

And ideas should be in java please as it is backend issue.

Comment: Hi just wanted to know, is this happening only on the Apple device.
If it's a common issue then check the stock level of given product and check is there any shrinkage event attached to it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the prompt response. It is happening to all indirect orders not just iPhoneX. I have checked the stock level and it has enough quantity available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to debug this issue, because the causes can be VERY different. Try adding some breakpoints right where is your original issue (stock alert) and go down the trace to see what caused that.

I don't really know your system specifics, that's why we need more input from you. If you don't know where to start, then maybe a screen sharing session would be the best, but for that you'll need to open a ticket at hybris (sap commerce cloud) team.